# Residuals of 1st regression as independent variable , "bad practice"?

Tags: regression, residuals

I have an independent variable [Y] that I want to do predict based on the "n" variables X1, X2, ..., Xn.
So,
I run "n" regression like:

- Y~X1
- Y~X2
- ...
- Y~Xn

From the "best"  regression, I want to use the regression residuals as the independent variable for a second regression with all the dependent variables again. For example, if the best regression was Y~X1, than I want to do:

- residuals_of(Y~X1)~X2
- residuals_of(Y~X1)~X3
- ...
- residuals_of(Y~X1)~Xn-1

The idea is to see if the errors are correlated with any of the other variables. 
If yes, then I could try a multiple regression with these correlated variables.

Is doing this considered a "bad practice"?

Comment: It's inefficient.  Whether it is useful or correct depends on how you intend to proceed.  What exactly do you mean by "try a multiple regression" and how would that differ, if at all, from simply starting out with a multiple regression of $Y$ against all the $X_i$?

Comment: Before trying this, I suggest visually inspecting scatterplots of all X variables against Y to determine if there is any obvious data transform such as log or exp that might help in the regression.

Comment: Suggest you read about 'forward selection' and 'backward elimination' procedures. After following advice of @JamesPhillips, both procedures will lead to some version of the 'best' subset of the $n$ variables. Because the potential predictor variables may be correlated among themselves, the two subsets may not be the same. [If you have 'favorite' $X$'s based on prior considerations (or at looking at scatterplots), you can specify that they be included. But check diagnostics to see that that your favorites aren't making things worse.]